# The add method should insert elements into a list in sorted order

Tags: java, linked-list

I have done this code for add the elements into `LinkedList`. Now I want to insert elements into a list in sorted order. How can I do this?

```
         public void add(String element)
                  {

                      if (isEmpty()) 
                      {
                          first = new Node(element);
                          last = first;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          // Add to end of existing list
                          last.next = new Node(element);
                          last = last.next;
                      }          
                  }
```

My Main class is this for Linkedlist and arraylist which calls the method of `SimpleLinkedList` class and `SimpleArrayListClass`

```
            package Comp10152_linkedlist;


            import java.util.Random;

            public class Comp10152_Lab4 
            {
               public static void main(String[] args)
              {
                final int NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS = 10;
                String names[] = {"Amy", "Bob", "Al", "Beth", "Carol", "Zed", "Aaron"};
                SimpleLinkedList ll = new SimpleLinkedList();
                final int TOTALOPERATIONS = names.length * NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS;

                Random random = new Random();

                for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS;i++)
                {
                  for (int j=0; j<names.length; j++)
                    ll.add(names[j]);
                }
                 System.out.println("The members of list are:");
                  System.out.println(ll);
                // remove half of the items in the list by selecting randomly from names
                for (int i=0; i<TOTALOPERATIONS/2;i++)
                {
                  ll.remove(names[random.nextInt(names.length)]);
                }
                System.out.println("The members of list are:");
                  System.out.println(ll);
                SimpleArrayList al = new SimpleArrayList();
                try
                {
                for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS;i++)
                {
                  for (int j=0;j<names.length;j++)
                     al.add(i,names[j]);
                }
                  System.out.println("The members of array are:");
                  System.out.println(al);

                // remove half of the items in the list by selecting randomly from names
                for (int i=0; i<TOTALOPERATIONS/2;i++)
                {
                  al.remove(names[random.nextInt(names.length)]);
                }   
                 System.out.println("The members of array are:");
                  System.out.println(al);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
              }     
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First insert the elements outside of the list, and then insert into the list by calling the add method.
How you sort elements outside the list depends on what data structures you use, what is the type of data, and what algorithms you want to apply.

Answer (score 0):

While insertion into the list itself add in the sorted order. 
First search the element in the sorted list which is greater than the element and then the element to be inserted and then add the new element before that.

Something like..

```
//Considering ascending order
public void add(String element) {
    if(isEmpty) {
        first = new Node(element);
        last = first;
    } else {
        currentNode = first;
        while(currentNode.next != null && currentNode.next.element > element) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }

        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        newNode.next = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Comp10152_linkedlist.SimpleLinkedList.add(SimpleLinkedList.java:108)
 at Comp10152_linkedlist.Comp10152_Lab4.main(Comp10152_Lab4.java:30)

Comment: And "currentNode.next.element" in this which element you used?

Comment: This is a rough code. Add conditions like currentNode != null. Also currentNode.next.element means accessing the element of the next connected node.